# Keeping PHP up-to-date on a Windows IIS server

Tags: php, security, iis, windows-server-2012, upgrade

On my Windows servers, *Microsoft Update* keeps IIS and ASP.NET updated automatically.
On my Linux/Debian servers, *cron-apt* keeps Apache/PHP/etc. updated (semi-)automatically.

However, I have not found a good solution yet for keeping **PHP on a Windows server** up-to-date. My current plan is to subscribe to the PHP announcement mailing list and manually upgrade PHP on the Windows server whenever a security upgrade is published.

Is there a well-established alternative that I am missing?

---

Note: This question has already received two close votes with the reason "*There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format*". Dear reader, if you decide to add your close vote to them, please be so kind as to add at least one of those "too many answers" to the question. ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, moving the web application that requires PHP to a Linux server is not an option for various reasons.

Comment: I do not know who downvoted this and who voted for close. XAMP is pretty common, so this should be a common concern.

Answer (score 1):

This is propably the best you can do at the moment.

It is a pain to update programs outside Microsoft - they use their own installers.

On Linux/Solaris/... this is pretty easy - even if a distribution does not contain a program you are done if the manufacturer maintains a repository - which you can simply include.

In other cases you can repackage the binary into a rpm/dpg and include it into your own repository.

With W2K12-means I would repackage PHP into an installer-image (only if there was a new release) and/or trigger a `cmd`-job to update the component (using the standard daily job scheduler).